# How to shorten the length of my cell reference code using a loop in VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Here's my VBA code:

```
Sub solver_macro()

    SolverOk SetCell:="$H$1", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$E$2:$E$33", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$5", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$G$5"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$9", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$G$9"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$13", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$G$13"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$17", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$G$17"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$21", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$G$21"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$25", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$G$25"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$29", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$G$29"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$33", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$G$33"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$H$1", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$E$2:$E$33", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$H$1", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$E$2:$E$33", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve

End Sub
```

My first try:

```
Sub solver_macro()

Dim i As Integer
Dim PERIOD As Integer

PERIOD = 7

    SolverOk SetCell:="$H$1", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$E$2:$E$33", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

        For i = 0 To PERIOD
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$5+4*i", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$G$5+4*i"
        Next i

    SolverOk SetCell:="$H$1", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$E$2:$5+4*PERIOD", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$H$1", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$E$2:$5+4*PERIOD", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve

End Sub
```

**Could you help me correcting this loop, please? Thank you in advance!**

Edit: Thank you for the answer. How can I do the same if I want to loop with letters instead of numbers?

Still the same code, but the data is horizontal. Therefore, the loop goes through the letters (columns) instead of numbers (rows) :

```
SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$88", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$G$89"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$K$88", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$K$89"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$O$88", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$O$89"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$S$88", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$S$89"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$W$88", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$W$89"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AA$88", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$AA$89"
```

Answer (score 1):

*These are possible VBA codes I would like to suggest you for the LOOP.*

```
    Dim lStart As Long, lFinish As Long
    Dim lCount1 As Long, lCount2 As Long
    Dim lIncrement As Long

    For lCount1 = lStart To lFinish Step lIncrement
        lCount2 = lCount1 / lIncrement

   SolverReset     

<< Your Code Lines Starts Here >>


   SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

   Next lCount
```

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: Thanks, Rajesh! Could you look at my Edit question, please?